# How to convert pdf to doc on free with c#

Tags: c#, pdf, converters, doc

I want with c# convert pdf(with images) to doc.

I looking for free solution, i tried so much, but yet i not found.

I will be happy if you will give me a simple ,work and free way.

thanks

Comment: You might ask for software recommendations on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Make sure you understood the rules of that site before posting there.

Comment: i dont want software
i want to programing it so it need this on this forum

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, go for it. This site is not a free coding service. You'll have to implement it and you can come back if something particular does not work.

Comment: Suggestion for a solution: step 1: read the PDF into memory,  step 2: convert it, step 3: write a DOC file to disk

Answer (score 0):

Same post here:
[Convert a pdf file to word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718503/convert-a-pdf-file-to-word-document/37719678#37719678)

You can try the solution I provided but note that this free version is limited to 10 pages of PDF file and you can only get the first 3 pages to word when converting PDF files.

Comment: Your link is dead, whether you remember what was mentioned in the other page?